# Microsoft Access SearchForRecord macro action useless?

Tags: ms-access, search-form

I have been trying to incorporate a built in macro action (SearchForRecord) in MS Access, however cannot get it to work for the life of me. There is minimal resources available online for this operation, and I've noticed that other people have struggled with the same issue.

I made a test database just to see if I could get it to work in the most basic form. I made a table with 3 columns (ID, Name, Colour) - I turned the table into a tabular form using the Form Wizard. I created a text box with a search button.

I then made a macro operation:

SearchForRecord

Object Type: Form

Object Name (Name of the Form) "frmNewSearch"

Record: First

Where Condition: ="txtIDSearch = '" & [Forms]![frmNewSearch]![txtSearchBox] & "'"

I took the where condition syntax directly from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/searchforrecord-macro-action

I set the button click event to the Macro that I made.

In theory, I enter the ID into the txtSearchBox and it should bring up the appropriate record within the same frmNewSearch form.

When I try this, nothing happens and it just sits on the first record. I am using MS Access 2016 - is the macro action maybe just not supported in this version?

If there is another way at approaching this it would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: I am sure it is supported in 2016 but stop struggling and use VBA. I never use macros. By 'tabular' do you mean a Continuous form?

Answer (score 0):

Referenced article states:

> Note the equal sign (=) at the beginning of the expression, and the
>   use of single quotation marks (') on either side of the text box
>   reference:
>   `="Description = '" & Forms![frmCategories]![txtDescription] & "'"`

Have to actually type = sign into argument. (Yes, I hear your ranting and cursing, but that's life.)

I presume txtIDSearch is name of textbox. The criteria must use name of field, which you say is ID. If ID is number type, don't use apostrophe delimiters (apostrophe delimiters are used for text fields, `#` delimiter for date/time, nothing for number type). So result will show like:

`Where Condition: = ="ID = " & [Forms]![frmNewSearch]![txtSearchBox]`

or since code and controls are on same form, simply:

`Where Condition: = ="ID = " & [txtSearchBox]`

However, both fail if form is a subform. This is because form is not open independently in Forms collection. A reference incorporating parent form name fails as well. Use VBA code methods.